# Get user coordinates within model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-geocoder

I've created my search and I'm trying to add conditionals for when certain parameters aren't provided.

This is what it looks like:

Controller:

```
@search = Availability.search(params)
```

Availability.rb:

```
  # Scopes for search filters
  scope :close_to, -> (venues) {where{facility.venue_id.in venues}}
  scope :activity, -> (activity) {where{facility.activities.id == activity}}
  scope :start_date, -> (datetime) {where{start_time >= datetime}}
  scope :end_date, -> (datetime) {where{end_time <= datetime}}
  scope :not_booked, -> {where(booking: nil)}
  scope :ordered, -> {order{start_time.desc}}
  scope :join, -> {joins{facility.activities}}

  # Main search function
  def self.search params
    # Check if date is nil
    def self.date_check date
      date.to_datetime if date
    end

    search = {
      venues: Venue.close_to(params[:geolocation]),
      activity: params[:activity].to_i,
      start_date: date_check(params[:start_time]) || DateTime.now,
      end_date: date_check(params[:end_time]) || 1.week.from_now
    }

    result = self.join.not_booked
    result = result.close_to(search[:venues])
    result = result.activity(search[:activity])
    result = result.start_date(search[:start_date])
    result = result.end_date(search[:end_date])
    result.ordered
  end
```

Venue.rb

```
  # Scope venues near geolocation
  scope :close_to, -> (coordinates) {near(get_location(coordinates), 20, units: :km, order: '').pluck(:id)}

  # If given coordinates, parse them otherwise generate them
  def self.get_location coordinates=nil
    if coordinates
      JSON.parse coordinates
    else
      location = request.location
      [location.latitude, location.longitude]
    end
  end
```

Everything works great except when I don't provide params[:geolocation]

I'd like to be able to return Availabilities which are in proximity to the user if the user doesn't enter the name of a city for example.

My url looks like this: `localhost:3000/s?activity=1`

From there, in the Venues model, I want to return Venues that are close to the users location.

I've been looking at Geocoder and using `request.location` but that doesn't work at the model level. Any suggestions?

I also considered adding the IP address to the url dynamically but if I did that, if a url was shared, it would return incorrect results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to be passing in the location from the controller to the model. Models do not have access to the `request`, because they are designed to be accessed in more than just the request cycle.

You should pass it to your `search` method as another argument.